# how to write R code to delete duplicate rows where one observation is the negative value of the duplicate?

Tags: r, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have some sales data where mistakes recorded at the point of sale are corrected afterward and the data set still contains records for the initial mistake then a duplicate of the mistake but with a negative price value.  How can I delete these observations conditionally so that 'if price < 0 remove observation and corresponding observation where price = price*-1, date = date, type = type, weight = weight'

The data is structured as

```
Date      Type     Weight     Price
5/5/16    A        15         34
5/5/16    A        15         -34
5/5/16    B        15         43
```

Another problem is not only do the redacted mistakes exist as duplicates but type, weight, and price entries have multiple duplicates which are valid. e.g. a sale can be made on the same date for 10 type A items at 15 lbs each for 34 dollars. - I added a column to count the number of duplicates of the absolute values test2 <- test %>% dplyr::group_by(Date, Type, Weight, ABS_Price) %>% dplyr::mutate(replicate=seq(n())) so how would I code 'if an observation has Price<0 then remove observation where replicate=x-1'

Comment: Can the logic here simply be, `if Price < 0, delete the row`?

Comment: I think they want to remove both the first and second rows: the row with a negative price means that the matching row is a mistake and should be removed

Comment: yes, both the positive and negative row should be removed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you're asking us to write code for you, or to write a tutorial explaining how to do it, but both are off-topic. We need to know what you tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: You might consider renaming the question into something like "Remove rows that have inexact duplicates". I believe this title will be easier to find .

Comment: Another problem is not only do the redacted mistakes exist as duplicates but type, weight, and price entries have multiple duplicates which are valid. e.g. a sale can be made on the same date for 10 type A items at 15 lbs each for 34 dollars. - I added a column to count the number of duplicates of the absolute values test2 <- test %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Date, Type, Weight, ABS_Price) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(replicate=seq(n()))   so how would I code 'if an observation has Price<0 then remove observation where replicate=x-1'

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward `dplyr` solution. Group rows by a combination of keys that define a duplicate (notice that we can apply transformations to columns on the fly) and filter singleton groups.

```
library(dplyr)

with.dups <- read.csv(...)
without.dups <- with.dups %>% 
    group_by(Date, Type, Weight, abs(Price)) %>% 
    filter(n()==1) %>%
    as.data.frame  # you can omit this part if you don't need to transform the resulting tibble table to a vanilla data.frame
```

Test data.

```
Date,Type,Weight,Price
5/5/16,A,15,34
5/5/16,A,15,-34
5/5/16,B,15,43
```

Test output

```
    Date Type Weight Price abs(Price)
1 5/5/16    B     15    43         43
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added an extra row to your example to catch the likely edge case of two transactions with matching keys -- we probably only want to delete the first match.

```
df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "Date      Type     Weight     Price
5/5/16    A        15         34
5/5/16    A        15         34
5/5/16    A        15         -34
5/5/16    B        15         43")
```

My approach is to look for matches where everything is the same (including the # of the transaction with those key values) but Price is reversed sign. If so, cut:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, Type, Weight, Price) %>%
  mutate(repeat_count = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

left_join(df2,
          df2 %>% mutate(Price = -Price, cut_flag = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(is.na(cut_flag)) %>%
  select(-cut_flag)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Date   Type  Weight Price repeat_count
  <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>        <int>
1 5/5/16 A         15    34            2
2 5/5/16 B         15    43            1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in base R using `duplicated`. Using @Jon Spring's data

```
df[!((duplicated(df[1:3]) | duplicated(df[1:3], fromLast = TRUE)) & 
     (duplicated(abs(df$Price)) | duplicated(abs(df$Price), fromLast = TRUE))), ]

#    Date Type Weight Price
#4 5/5/16    B     15    43
```

This is assuming you have `Date` , `Type` and `Weight` at column `1:3` respectively. If their position is not fixed you can also select them by name

```
df[!((duplicated(df[c("Date", "Type", "Weight")]) | 
      duplicated(df[c("Date", "Type", "Weight")], fromLast = TRUE)) & 
      (duplicated(abs(df$Price)) | duplicated(abs(df$Price), fromLast = TRUE))), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly different from Ronak but similar premise using *which()*

```
df$price <- abs(df$price)  #take absolute value, making all entries positive

dups <- which(duplicated(df)) #find place of duplicates, where all columns match


newdf <- df[-c(dups-1,dups),]
```

All duplicate cases removed and immediate case prior to each duplicate as well

Comment: This only works, if duplicates follow each other. If such order cannot be guaranteed, you should sort the rows beforehand. Moreover, you have overwritten an existing column.

Comment: The example code suggests that such order may exist: My answer applies when it does, as I have specified. To each his own about overwriting existing columns for what makes sense for one's own code.

Comment: I just think that both things are important enough to highlight in your answer.